Función Insertar en PSeInt
Estoy intentando implementar una función en PSeInt llamada insertar(SO,SD,P) que inserta la cadena SO en la cadena SD a partir de la posición P. Por ejemplo, transforma la cadena Curso de PSeInt en la cadena Curso de Programación en PSeInt.
Estoy usando el perfil estricto que toma los índices de subcadenas y arreglos en base 0.
Ejemplo 1:

frase1 = "Hola Mundo"
frase2 = "Maravilloso "
resultado = insertar(frase1, frase2, 5); debería dar como resultado "Hola Maravilloso Mundo".

Ejemplo 2:

frase1 = "Programación en PSeInt"
frase2 = "Lenguaje de "
resultado =
insertar(frase1, frase2, 0); debería dar como resultado "Lenguaje de
Programación en PSeInt".

Ejemplo 3:

frase1 = "Python es genial"
frase2 = " y muy popular"
resultado =
insertar(frase1, frase2, 6); debería dar como resultado "Python y muy
popular es genial".

Salida esperada:
Frase1 modificada: Hola Maravilloso Mundo
Salida obtenida:
Frase1 modificada: oMaravilloso
Este es el código que tengo:
Proceso InsertarFrases
    Definir frase1, frase2, resultado Como Cadena;
    
    frase1 <- "Hola Mundo";
    frase2 <- "Maravilloso ";
    
    Escribir "Se introducirá la frase2 en la frase1";
    Escribir "Frase1: ", frase1;
    Escribir "Frase2: ", frase2;
    
    // Llamar a la función de inserción en la posición correcta
    resultado <- Insertar(frase1, frase2, 5); // Insertar frase2 en frase1 en la posición 5
    
    Escribir "Frase1 modificada: ", resultado;
FinProceso

Funcion resultado <- Insertar(destino, origen, posicion)
    Definir resultado Como Cadena;
    Definir longitudDestino, longitudOrigen, i Como Entero;
    
    longitudDestino <- Longitud(destino); // Longitud de la cadena destino
    longitudOrigen <- Longitud(origen);   // Longitud de la cadena origen
    
    // Inicializar la cadena resultado como vacía
    resultado <- "";
    
    // Copiar la parte de destino antes de la posición
    Para i <- 0 Hasta posicion - 1 Hacer
        resultado <- concatenar(resultado,Subcadena(destino, i, 0));
    FinPara
    
    // Insertar la cadena origen en la posición especificada
    resultado <- concatenar(resultado,origen); // Concatenar la cadena origen
    
    // Copiar la parte de destino después de la posición
    Para i <- posicion Hasta longitudDestino Hacer
        resultado <- concatenar(resultado,Subcadena(destino, i, 0));
    FinPara
FinFuncion

¿Como se puede solucionar el error?

Hola Alejandro, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el resultado obtenido (como texto)?:

Y ejecútalo y pruébalo. Necesito respuestas a mi pedido, no preguntas

Seguro que yo no te voy a ayudar.

Si alguien trata de ayudarte, lo comun es tratar de ayudar a esa persona que trata de ayudarte... si no mostras los resultados obtenidos, obligas a alguien a hacer todo el trabajo de testeo, cuando vos lo tenes ahi mismo, y podrias decir que resultado obtenes que es erroneo...}

Ya puse la salida esperada y la obtenida

No se que hace concatenar.. pero si tenes la funcion subcadena ahi, no seria mas facil usarla para partir la cadena original?

Hace adjunción entre 2 cadenas

ok.. y porque no vas agregando un print de resultado en cada iteracion para ver como va quedando y cuando falla?

y lo otro que te decia, es que si subcadena devuelve ya una subcadena del tamaño especificado, no tiene sentido ir uno a uno.. basta con que devuelvas las dos subcadenas y pongas en el medio la otra...

¿Y eso como se hace?

Lo primero que tenes que aprender es a depurar.
Para ello, nada mejor que usar la función escribir a cada rato para ver que esta pasando..
Como la documentación de pseint es bastante escasa y mala (y la verdad, no tiene mucho sentido enseñar con este lenguaje), cuando le ponemos escribir dentro del primer for (para):
Para i <- 0 Hasta posicion - 1 Hacer
    resultado <- concatenar(resultado,Subcadena(destino, i, 0));
    Escribir resultado
FinPara

Nos damos cuenta que subcadena no esta haciendo nada...
investigando un poco, y jugando con la función, podemos entender que la función esa recibe tres parámetros, la cadena a partir, la posición inicial desde donde partir, y la posición hasta donde partir.
Si ponemos 0 al final, no funciona.
Pero, sabiendo esto, podemos simplificar todo tu código a una versión que haga lo que vos querés sin tener que recorrer nada.
Porque básicamente lo que te piden es corta esta cadena acá, agrega la otra, y después agrega todo el resto de la original.
Y para eso, si usamos subcadena como corresponde y concatenar
Tu función se puede resumir en lo siguiente:
Funcion resultado <- Insertar(destino, origen, posicion)
    Definir resultado Como Cadena;
    Definir longitudDestino Como Entero;
    
    longitudDestino <- Longitud(destino); // Longitud de la cadena destino
    
    // Inicializar la cadena resultado como vacía
    resultado <- "";
    resultado <- Subcadena(destino, 0, posicion-1) //Agregamos desde destino a posicion y restamos -1 a la posición pues los índices están en base 0
    resultado <- Concatenar(resultado, origen) //le agregamos la otra cadena a resultado
    resultado <- Concatenar(resultado,  Subcadena (destino, posicion, longitudDestino)) //Agregamos la parte final desde donde cortamos más 1 caracter
FinFuncion

Nota al margen, se puede arreglar tu funcion arreglando lo que hace subcadena.. si cambias el 0 por i+1 se arregla todo... pero no tiene sentido
Y otra nota, digo que esto no tiene ningún sentido, porque sacando que los nombres de las cosas están en español, en casi cualquier lenguaje, escribís esto mismo en la misma cantidad de líneas llamando a las funciones en inglés (substr, mid, len, concat) o las versiones de cada lenguaje, que existen y hacen exactamente lo mismo.
